# How to restart a pc with out logging in to Local Admin Account?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have an issue at my workplace. Its complete configured with a domain server and workstation computers added to a domain, and all computers configured under group policy rules. So Now... How to restart a computer without logging in to the Local administrator account. The complete setup is configured by my senior admin. He is located at different location. Please help.

Comment: You don't need local admin to restart a pc... If you did security policies would be a nightmare to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the shutdown command:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

It allows you to reboot computers remotely using the /m command.